# Count total number of occurrences through all the lines through all the files in a given branch of git repository

Tags: bash, git, shell, awk, grep

I can find all the lines containing "my string" pattern in a single branch of my git repository by following command

```
git grep "my string" my_branch
```

Say, it results in following

> my_branch: file1:file1 What is "**my string**"?
>   my_branch: file2:file2 Hello, "**my string**" is just "**my string**"!

We see 3 occurrences in two lines of two files. I can count these lines via

```
git grep "my string" my_branch | wc -l
```

It will result in

> 2

The question is how to get the exact number of string occurrences through all the lines through all the files in a given branch? Is it possible to run some command or script that will give me **3** in my example, not **2**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-o` option in `grep` for your requirement and pass it to `wc -l` for the count:

Inside `man grep`:

```
-o, --only-matching
              Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.
```

This should work for you:

`git grep -o "my string" my_branch | wc -l`

Please note that to use `-o` option, the **git** version must be **2.18** or higher.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but `git grep -o ...` throws the following warning: `error: unknown switch `o'`

Comment: @dhilt: Most probably, it looks like the git version you are using is bit old and is not the recent one?

Comment: Yes, I had 2.16. Updating git (to 2.25 in my case) I was able to run `git grep -o ...` and I finally got right result

Comment: @dhilt: Glad that it worked for you now!!! you can accept and upvote any of the suitable answers here,cheers :-)

Comment: I updated your answer by adding 2.18 git version requirement and accepted it as this is the only way I got the correct result

Answer (score 6):

The `-o` option [was introduced in 2.19](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep/2.19.0#git-grep--o).
In previous versions, you can use `git show` and combine it with a standard `grep` call:

```
$ git show my_branch | grep -o 'my string' | wc -l
```

Comment: It's weird, but it gives me incorrect result, which is dramatically less than needed. I updated git locally and was able to run `git grep -o`, and that gave me correct result. Also, `git show | awk` approach gives the same incorrect result as the `git show | grep` one. What can be wrong on my side?

Answer (score 1):

Why `grep` is NOT giving correct results is,since it is looking for string in each line and if a line is having more than 1 occurrence of string then also it is counting it as 1 occurrence.

***Example of `grep` not counting multiple occurrences of string on same line:***

Let's say we have following Input_file:

```
cat Input_file
test my_string
la bla bla
my_string
bla bla
```

Now when we run `grep` command it gives as follows:

```
grep "my_string" Input_file | wc -l
2
```

Now lets put multiple occurrences of a string in a single line:

```
cat Input_file
test my_string
la bla bla
my_string my_string
bla bla

grep "my_string" Input_file | wc -l
2
```

---

---

So if permitted then you could try `awk` where you need not to use 2 programs(`grep` + `wc`), also for `git` command taken reference from @UnbearableLightness's answer here.

```
git show my_branch |awk '{sum+=gsub(/my string/,"&")} END{print sum}'
```